# Loopback HasAndBelongToMany in MySQL

Tags: mysql, loopbackjs

I have a Loopback application and I try to connect it to the MySQL datasource and migrate my models. In order, to do this I use `autoupdate()`.

But when I open the MySQL database to inspect the result I don't see the created table for any HasAndBelongsToMany relationship.

[Here](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/HasAndBelongsToMany+relations) in the docs it says it should create a separate table. I don't see it.

How does Loopback handle HasAndBelongsToMany relationships?
Is this a limitation of `autoupdate()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried and read a number of things but unfortunately in the end I had to create the relation tables manually.

I would love to hear a better a solution if such a thing exists.